# How to change value of a button Typescript / React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization

I have a button with which I handle my language switcher, it is set up to handle cookie, url changes and now I need to make it to change my translations on page as well. The `<img>` tag is used for changing the country flag.

```
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                        const locale =
                           router.locale === 'en-us'? 'da-dk': 'en-us';
                            setCookie(locale);
                            {handleOnclick;}
                     router.push(/${locale}`,
                                `/${locale}`,
                                {
                                 locale: false,
                                }); }} >
                        {router.locale === 'en-us' ? (
                            <img src={
                                    menuItems.data.body[5].items[0].image
                                        .url}/> ) : (
                            <img
                                src={
                                    menuItems.data.body[4].items[0].image
                                        .url
                                }/>)}
                    </button>
```

The function of switching between languages `handleOnClick` is working just fine (tested) This is an example:

```
<button value="da" onClick={handleOnclick}>
    Danish
</button>
<button value="en" onClick={handleOnclick}>
    English
</button>
```

But now I need to change the value onClick, since I am having only one button instead of 2, but I don't know how to exactly do it

Comment: Store the language as a state in the component. Then you can use {language == "en" ? "English" : "Danish"}

The handleOnClick would do setState({language: event.target.value})

Let me know if you want more information and I can write up an answer

Comment: Do you mean to use it in my handleOnClick like setLanguage({language: e.target.value}) ?

Comment: @GregM it did not work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a state and switch its value based on the previous value it had.

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en');

// if your project is written in typescript you can use below line of code
// const [language, setLanguage] = useState<'en' | 'da'>('en');

const handleOnclick = () => {
  setLanguage(prevState => (prevState === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en'));
  // it can also be written like this
  // setLanguage(language === 'en' ? 'da' : 'en');
  // But the 1st is more robust when the event happens more frequently.
};
```

Then write the button like this

```
<button value={language} onClick={handleOnclick}>
  {language === 'en' ? 'English' : 'Danish'}
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amir for the post, but it doesn't fit my case really. I do have an hook `const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en')` and tried also your version of handleOnclick funtion, but you can see I am not switching between text but between flags - click on flag language, url will switch and cookie will be stored. I set up everything except the handleOnclick funtion - page translation, which does not work and I dont know how to implement it

Comment: @Eliot all of your logic you already specified in the onClick can be moved to `handleOnclick` function. You can set the cookie there. 

You're using the cookie to determine how the page loads which means when you do `const [language, setLanguage] = useState('en')` you should instead do `const [language, setLanguage] = useState(getCookieFunction(locale))`